# Tensor Objects of different size

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I am attempting to implement a CNN, but I have run into a minor issue.

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 28, 28, 1])

# 0-9 digits recognition => 10 classes.
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10])

...code for layers...
...etc....

# Output has a shape of [batch_size, 10]
logits = tf.layers.dense(inputs=dropout, units=10)

# Softmax layer for deriving probabilities.
pred = tf.nn.softmax(logits, name="softmax_tensor")

# Convert labels to a one-hot encoding.
onehot_labels = tf.one_hot(indices=tf.cast(y, tf.int32), depth=10)
loss = tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy(onehot_labels=onehot_labels, logits=logits)
```

As is visible, the `losses` function will not run properly because `logits` and `onehot_labels` are of different shapes. `logits` is `shape=(2,)` whereas `onehot_labels` is `shape=(3,)` and this is because it depends on the `y` placeholder which is `[batch_size, 10]`.

I am not sure how to fix this. I need to change the shape of either of these variables, but I am not sure which one. Does the CNN require `y`, which are the labels, to have `batch_size` as an argument? Where am I going wrong?

Some extra info, I intend to run the CNN within a session as so..

```
# Assign the contents of `batch_xs` to variable `x`.
_, c = sess.run([train_op, loss], feed_dict={x:sess.run(batch_xs), y:batch_ys})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your label data are the actual classes, then the code should be:

```
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 1])
...
onehot_labels = tf.one_hot(indices=tf.cast(y, tf.int32), depth=10)
loss = tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy(onehot_labels=onehot_labels, logits=logits)
```

Otherwise, your label must be already one-hot data, then the code should be:

```
# y is already one-hot label data.
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10])
...
loss = tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy(onehot_labels=y, logits=logits)
```

Please refer to [mint tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/mnist/beginners) for an example.

Comment: Never mind you're right. I am using a different dataset from the CNN tutorial, my data is already converted to one hot labels